# How does website like SketchFab protect their 3d model on WebGL?

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, 3d, webgl

I am recently experimenting how to protect a 3d model for WebGL. I know it's impossible to be perfect but I still want it to have some level of security.

Let's take Sketchfab as reference. I see that there is software 3D ripper that can rips the model correctly. But not Ninja Ripper, as it only returns a broken mesh. In my own prototype, i tried to apply offset on vertice of my model, and write a simple vert/frag shader to neutralize offset. Unfortunately , this method seems not working. Ninja Ripper can rip it with no visible problem.

May i get some suggestion on this?